# How to navigate from one view to other view using UIPageControl?

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

I have page control but  not navigating to other view. so please provide the solution.

```
    pageControl=[[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,380,320,40)];
    pageControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    pageControl.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
    [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(pageAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [pageControl setHighlighted:YES];


-(void)pageAction:(UIPageControl*)control
{       
    [self displayNextPage];
    [self displayPreviousPage];
}
```

Thank You,
Madan Mohan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
-(void)pageAction:(UIPageControl*)control
{       
int page = pageControl.currentPage;
CGRect frame = pagingScrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = (myScrollView.frame.size.width * page);
[myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How can we do this when a button is pressed in one of the views?

Answer (score 0):

Swift :

```
       func changeImageOnPageControl(sender: UIPageControl) {
            let page = sender.currentPage;
            var frame = self.scrollViewBase.frame;
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollViewBase.frame.size.width * CGFloat(page);
            self.scrollViewBase.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true);

        }
```